# iphone application design

Tags: iphone

What would I put into my root controller in an application that will have multiple tabs, where is tab is a navigation controller?

Do I create derived classes of the navigation controller, where each one manages its own view controllers and the root manages the tabbar and list of navigation controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "Tab Bar Application" template in XCode will get you started on this.

Once created, your `MainWindow.xib` file (under "Resources" in the project file) should have a single `UITabBarController`, which is added to the `UIWindow` in the code in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your application delegate.

So, the app delegate only "knows" about the Tab Bar Controller.  Then, in Interface Builder, you can specify a separate XIB file to load for each tab.  In those XIB files, you would want a `UINavigationController`.

If you do it this way, the UITabBarController will take care of instantiating all of the UINavigationControllers for you (nice!).